# validate dynamic fields using setValidators

Tags: angular, validation

I am using dynamic form control to create dynamic fields 
by using reference of https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/creating-form-controls-dynamically-in-angular-7-project
I want to validate dynamic fields using `setValidators` and `updateValueAndValidity` in Angular 6.

Below is syntax I have used but it's not working.

```
(<FormArray>this.addQuestionForm.get('other')).setValidators([Validators.required]);
(<FormArray>this.addQuestionForm.get('other')).updateValueAndValidity();
```

Also let me know how to delete dynamically added field with reference of "`<FormArray>this.addQuestionForm.get('other')`"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a loop on each control of (this.addQuestionForm.get('other')) and apply validation on each component

```
(<FormArray>this.addQuestionForm.get('other')).controls.forEach((control) => {
    control.setValidators([Validators.required]);
    control.updateValueAndValidity();
});
```

If you want to delete dynamically added field in formArray, then you have to get index of element you want to delete

As FormArray class has removeAt which takes the index. If you do not know the index, you can do a workaround:

```
this.addQuestionForm.get('other').removeAt(index);
```

Comment: Hi Kinjal,

I have tried above given code it works for "removeAt" but not for apply validation on each component.
Please suggest another way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is setting a required validation on `FormArray`. Because in JavaScript an empty array is also true.

What you can do is set a `minLength` validation on the `FormArray` field.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hi Himanshu Mittal,

I have tried by minLength validation but it not worked for me.
Please suggest another way.

Thanks